# What does an apostrophe mean in a function?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, notation

In a workbook, I saw the function $f(x)=x^2$. Then, there was the same function with an apostrophe $f'(x)$. It was stated that $f'(x)=2x$.

What is the apostrophe, and why does it change the function?

Comment: It's a very common notation for the derivative.

Comment: $f'(x)=\frac{df}{dx}$

Comment: Please note that this is actually a "prime" symbol, rather than an apostrophe. Here in Britain, we read this "$f$ dash(ed) of $x$", though I hear they do things rather differently in America. I think "$f$ prime of $x$" is fine?

Comment: I suppose we need the ask the OP do they know what the derivative is?

Comment: @Au101 As an American, I prefer the "dash" enunciation, but you're right that "prime" is very common here.

Comment: Wow, what a blast. This question was asked more than a year ago, and it sky-rocketed into 9k views only today! Crazy!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It means the first derivative of the function with respect to the variable $x$

So $f(x)=x^2$, $f'(x)=2x$ and even 2 can be used where you get $f''(x)=2$ because it's the second derivative, after that you don't use the primes anymore.

Comment: "It means the first derivation of the function...": it's "derivative", not "derivation".

Comment: My bad, thank you for the correction :)

Comment: I've seen $f'''(x)$. 4 primes is pushing it.

Answer (score 1):

That is **Lagrange's notation for derivatives**.

> One of the most common modern notations for differentiation is due to Joseph Louis Lagrange. In Lagrange's notation, a prime mark denotes a derivative. If $f$ is a function, then its derivative is written $f'(x)$
>   — [Notation for differentiation (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notation_for_differentiation#Lagrange.27s_notation)

> In Lagrange's notation, the derivative of $f$ is expressed as $f'$ (pronounced "f prime").
>   — [Derivative notation review (Khan Academy)](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/ap-calculus-ab/basic-differentiation-ab/basic-differentiation-rules-ab/a/derivative-notation-review)